# Unable to attach Debugger from VS 2017 to Azure app service for ASP.NET CORE 2.2.1 app

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2017

I am new to azure, I have hosted a **asp.net core web api  in Azure App services**. I am able to browse the azure link. However I am getting some internal error while accessing the service.

To find out the error I want to debug the application by attaching to visual studio. But while attaching the debugger I am getting below error as shown in the image.

[ERROR POPUP WHILE ATTACHING DEBUGGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXkmV.png)
[image]

---

Error: *"Unable to find a process called dotnet with arguments .\APICore.dll. The process may still be starting, please try again."*

### APICore is my Web api project.

I have verified that REMOTE Debugging is enabled.

1. Application is ASP.NET Core.
2. Visual Studio is VS 2017 community
       edition.

Answer (score 24):

I've had the same problem today, and this is what worked out for me:

1) Instead of attaching the debugger via Server Explorer, go to **Debug > Attach to Process...**

2) Set the **Connection Target** to your App Service url **without http** and with port 4022.
So, http://myappservice.azurewebsites.net would become **myappservice.azurewebsites.net:4022**

3) Hit the **Refresh** button. You will be prompted for credentials to access your App Service. Those can be found on the MSDeploy publish profile of your **publish profile file**:

```
<publishData>
  <publishProfile profileName="myappservice - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy" 
                  publishUrl="myappservice.azurewebsites.net:443" 
                  userName="{USERNAME}" userPWD="{PASSWORD}" ...>
    <databases />
  </publishProfile>
  <publishProfile profileName="myappservice - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" ...>
    <databases />
  </publishProfile>
</publishData>
```

4) After the available process show up, select **w3wp.exe** and hit **Attach**

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to download a publish profile from Azure to be able to see the username and password. If you generate one through Visual Studio the password is encrypted and won't work

Comment: @JonathanBrown That's a good point. I did indeed use a publish profile from Azure in my solution

Comment: Great. For Visual Studio 2019 the port number changes to 4024

Answer (score 1):

There are few options that you can try out and see if that helps.

- Ensure Visual Studio is opened in Administrator Mode and follow the
      same steps.
- Open the Outbound ports  4022 for VS 2017 on corporate firewall.
- You can also go through the below links in order to Remote debug the
     application

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure?view=vs-2017#remote_debug_azure_app_service

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same issue, tried several things (open in Admin mode, open outbound port 4022, 'Attach debugger', 'Attach to process') but nothing worked.

Just switched from VS 2017 Community edition to Visual Studio 2019 - Enterprise edition and now it instantly works flawless:

- Published my Azure App Service in Debug configuration
- Attach debugger via the Cloud Explorer
- Set the breakpoints and hit them when sending requests to the API

So perhaps switching to 2019 will solve it for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above using a regular
"Attach to Process" using creds from a publish profile downloaded from the portal worked for me.
VS2019 (community and professional, multiple azure accounts, multiple machines, physical and virtual) here, and the cloud explorer "AttachDebugger" never worked.  In fact it hung vstudio at "attaching to process" and had to kill VStudio from task manager to stop it.

Strange because at other companies/projects I didn't have this problem.  For years I relied on debugging azure from desktop for a variety of projects.  This particular software I inherited, and I expect that something in its origination or construction (there are several ..."sub optimal"... aspects to it).